# What an I doing wrong with lhs Unit Eigenvectors in Python for DRGroot model Social Networking

Tags: python, numpy, social-networking

What an I doing wrong with lhs Unit Eigenvectors in Python for DRGroot model for Social Networking:

```
The influence array at time 0 is:
1/3, 1/3 1/3
1/2, 1/2, 0
0, 0.25, 0.75

It is suppose to converge to the array:
3/11 4/11 4/11
3/11 4/11 4/11
3/11 4/11 4/11
```

You are suppose to be able to get the convergence array by taking the left hand side unit vector of the array at time 0.

My linear algebra can be rusty at times and I want to try this in python:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import eig
np.set_printoptions(precision=4)
limT = np.array([(0.33,0.33,0.33),(0.5,0.5,0.0),(0.0,0.25,0.75)])
w, vl, vr = eig(limT, left=True)
lhs = vl.conj().T.dot(limT)
>>> lhs
array([[-0.0678,  0.0335,  0.0335],
       [-0.4669, -0.6231, -0.6231],
       [-0.2958, -0.1006,  0.3904]])
lhs/np.linalg.det(lhs)
array([[ -2.385 ,   1.1795,   1.1795],
       [-16.4266, -21.9221, -21.9221],
       [-10.4052,  -3.5378,  13.7349]])
```

The final array is obviously not:

```
3/11 4/11 4/11
3/11 4/11 4/11
3/11 4/11 4/11
```

I could have misunderstood several issues and appreciate the assistance.

Comment: Don't you essentially want to find lhs unit eigenvector which corresponds to the eigenvalue 1?  If so, `w, vl, vr = eig(limT, left=True)`.  Then print `w`. Say the third eigenvalue is 1. Then, `s = vl[:,2]`. Then normalize: `s /= s.sum()`.  Now you have your unit eigenvector.

Comment: Hi Bill yes that's what I am trying to do! I am weak on using  eigenvectors: I tried:printing w, the eigenvalues and got array([ 0.0827+0.j,  0.9973+0.j,  0.5000+0.j]), so the third value is 0.5. I tried normalizing "s /= s.sum()", but my eigenvector is  >>> s
array([ 50.,  17., -66.]) and not 3/11 4/11 4/11. I appreciate you help and any references!

Comment: Dumb question; why s =vl:,2]? Also why do I need to scale by s /= s.sum(). I am eager to learn!

Comment: 1.) According to the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html), the eigenvector which corresponds to the `i`th eigenvalue (`w[i]`) is `v[:,i]`.  When you print `w`, the second eigenvalue is 0.9973 ~ 1. So the eigenvector you want is `v[:,1]`.

Comment: 2.) The eigenvectors returned by `eig` are not unit eigenvectors.  Unit means the sum of the entries is 1. Therefore, to make them unit eigenvectors, divide by `vector.sum()`.